# What are the largest numerical units that the median-wealthy person in Western civilization was aware of through the centuries?

Tags: language

For example, I just [searched Shakespeare](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-keyword.php) and saw hundreds of references to "thousand", a dozen or two references to "million", and no occurrences of the word "billion".

Update: The Wikipedia article on the [long and short scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales) was useful.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. How often do you think that Shakespeare would have had cause to write about 1,000,000,000,000 of something? ([The number "one billion" in "British English" used to mean one million million](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/how-many-is-a-billion) )

Comment: 'Through the centuries' is awfully broad so you might want to edit it to avoid it being closed. As for 'billion', see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion.

Comment: Needs a tighter timeline and some sort of definition of "average person". Does it mean a literate person, a numerate person, an educated person, or a serf. By "average" is the intent "arithmetic mean", mode, or median across the population. Geographic tightening is also essential, as an "average" Amazonian tribesperson even today probably has no conception of numbers much larger than a few thousand.

Comment: Shakespeares not average! The average man through the centuries and around the globe would have been illiterate and not very numerate. The average tradesman probably knew up to his thousands and the average hunter-gatherer probably went one, two, three then many.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: On the contrary, Shakespeare made a living by writing plays that appealed to the common people of his place & time.

Comment: @jamesqf - Indeed, but to do it as well as he did took *uncommon* skill with languages. Not to mention the bonus meanings he threw in for nobles and the educated.

Comment: @Obie 2.0: It took uncommon skill to put words together in the way Shakespeare did, but the words & language used were perfectly comprehensible to the average person in that time & place.  Still are, bar a few shifts in meaning and terms that have fallen out of use.

Comment: @jamesqf: It's actually much easier to understand Shakespeare when it's acted than when just read on the page; this is why the common man could understand him even if the language is uncommon; also, poetry was far more common and understood than it is now - they didn't have TV and movies back then; Shakespeare was taken to be common by his fellow dramatists as he was not a university man; they said 'he was an upstart crow beautified with our feathers'!

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: I agree that the spoken Shakespeare is better than written - the Arkangel recordings are some of my favorite listening for long drives.  Though I would not call most of the plays "poetry" ("Comedy of Errors" and "Midsummer Night's Dream" being exceptions).

Comment: @jamesqf: He's primarily a dramatist but he uses the conventions of poetic verse in his plays. To see the difference you only need to compare it to modern plays that use more colloquial language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I haven't read it, you may be interested in the book, *[Everything and More: A Compact History of Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_and_More_(book))* by David Foster Wallace. I believe this book discusses anthropological studies showing that in most hunter-gather societies three is effectively the highest number (anything higher than four is refered to with a concept of "many").

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_large_numbers), by the 5th century BCE the Vedic civilization gave names to many very large numbers including multiple infininties. The largest number the Ancient Greeks had a word for was only one hundred million, but Archimides worked with numbers up to 10^64.

According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/billion), the concept of "a billion" made its way from French into English by about Shakespeare's time.